# Solving mixed-integer nonlinear program with Gurobi in drake

Tags: drake

thanks for your great job in drake.
i want to solve a mixed-integer nonlinear program (MINLP) with darke. While gurobi support MINLP but while i add a nonlinear constraint in MathematicalProgram and solve it with Gurobi, it will get error msg

```
GurobiSolver is unable to solve because a GenericConstraint was declared but is not supported
```

My question is since Gurobi supports MINLP, why Drake does not support? Is there any technical issue? Can I modify the `GurobiSolver` Class of Drake to support MINLP?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What type of mixed-integer nonlinear constraint do you have? Does it have any special structure? Is it quadratic? Gurobi can only handle a very specific type of nonlinear nonconvex constraint, which include bilinear constraint, as mentioned in https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/11466556605713-MINLP-solver and https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/py_model_agc_xxx.html

Comment: The nonlinear terms in my problem is about rotation. the SE(3) body pose and the end-effector point as well as some binary variable are Decision Variables in my problem, and i want to build a constraint between them. So the rotation matrix must be include in the constraint, which cause the nonlinear.

Comment: BTW, we do provide a method to relax the SO(3) constraint as mixed-integer convex constraint, in https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/solvers/mixed_integer_rotation_constraint.h. You can see the mathematical derivation in https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hongkai-Dai/publication/333057797_Global_inverse_kinematics_via_mixed-integer_convex_optimization/links/5cda454f299bf14d959509b1/Global-inverse-kinematics-via-mixed-integer-convex-optimization.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Drake may not yet support all of new MINLP solving capabilities of Gurobi version 11. To always benefit from the latest features and improvements, you should use Gurobi directly, e.g., via the gurobipy interface.

Here is an overview of the new features introduced in v11: https://www.gurobi.com/events/whats-new-in-gurobi-11-0/